# Добавить запятую элементу, если он не последний

Tags: html, css

Как с помощью css добавить элементу запятую, если после него есть еще элементы? Элементы добавляются динамически.

[Разметка такая](https://jsfiddle.net/lilubanana/98mf6b3L/):

```
<span class="tags-list ">
    <a href="#">элемент1</a>
    <a href="#">элемент2</a>
    <a href="#">элемент3</a>
</span>
```

Изначально неизвестно сколько элементов выведется, один или несколько.

Comment: *Элементы добавляются динамически.* каким средствами это происходит: [tag:javascript]?

Comment: да, загружаются через ajax

Comment: @MarinaVoronova тогда может логику вывода там и организовать? через `css` будет `.tags-list a:not(:last-child):after {
  content: ',';
}` ........ но при динамическом добавлении не факт, что получится

Comment: т.е. с сервера приходит массив элементов который Вы хотите вывести через запятую?

Comment: если я правильно понимаю, то да

Comment: а почему при динамическом добавлении может не получиться?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, добавь ответом

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, как раз у css с динамическим добавлением всё шикарно :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Чтобы вопрос не остался без ответа, сделала так:

```css
.tagswidget {
  font-size: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.tagswidget .tags-list {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 85%;
}
.tags-list a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.tags-list a:not(:last-child):after {
  content: ', ';
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="tagswidget">
  <div class="tags-list">
    <a href="#">text</a>
    <a href="#">text</a>
    <a href="#">text</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Получает все кроме последнего элемненты через

```
Array.prototype.slice.call(elements, 0, -1)
```

Таким образом не надо создавать лишний массив из `NodeList` чтобы выполнить `slice`.

Дальше через `forEach` перебирается полученный массив `elementsWithoutLast` и для каждого элемента добавляется запятая в конец: `i.textContent += ','`.

```js
const elements = document.querySelectorAll('.tags-list a')
const elementsWithoutLast = Array.prototype.slice.call(elements, 0, -1)

elementsWithoutLast.forEach(i => i.textContent += ',')
```

```html
<div class="tags-list">
  <a href="#">foo</a>
  <a href="#">bar</a>
  <a href="#">baz</a>
</div>
```